# PHP $_GET not get value of RewriteRule in case of "index"

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem. I'm trying to get this url:

```
mySite.com/index.php?url=category/value1/value2/value3
```

From this:

```
MySite.com/category/value1/value2/value3
```

I have this .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

everything is working fine if category is everything but "index", so if I put the URL:

```
MySite.com/content/tv/color
```

The array $_GET is equal to:

```
Array
(
    [url] => content/tv/color/
)
```

but when i put:

```
MySite.com/index/option1/option2
```

the array is empty

```
Array()
```

I checked my apache.conf file and I can't see the problem.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin user@site.com

        DocumentRoot /home/htdocs
        <Directory />
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/htdocs>
                #>>>>>HERE I HAVE MY TEST APP <<<<<<<<
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                RewriteEngine ON
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /simplesaml /var/simplesamlphp/www
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You're certain `index` doesn't exist as a folder? Also you don't need the `$` in your regexp

Comment: Yes, it does't exist as a folder, thanks for the $ advice.

Comment: @Mikeroguez: so what about my answer?

Comment: @zerkms I have not tried it, but it sounds very logical, that was the default settings, just moved the AllowOverride, I'll try in a moment and vote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off `MultiViews` option by prepending minus sign `-` before it like `-MultiViews`.

Actually I'm not sure why you turned it on explicitly. Was it just a config copy-paste?

Also if you don't need `FollowSymLinks` (I'm sure you don't need it) - turn it off as well.